# How can I append two copies of the same image in one function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is a js snippet of code that's been giving me problems. I'm attempting to append 2 img layers with different dynamically generated HTML tags but browsers refuse to render the code correctly.
the desired outcome is for

```
dropzone.append(img);
dropzone.append(imgIn);
```

append 2 images with different 2 indexes and do this hundreds of times in a mosaic
here is a link to the android app this code is for https://www.webintoapp.com/store/107768

```
function hueChange() {
  for(let image = 0; image < mosaicCount; image++) {
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      let imgIn = document.createElement('imgIn');
      img.setAttribute("id", image)
      img.setAttribute("width", screenWidth/16 + "px")
      imgIn.setAttribute("id", "imgIn" + image)
      imgIn.setAttribute("width", screenWidth/16 + "px")
      img.src = reader.result;
      imgIn.src = reader.result;

      dropzone.append(img);   //this doesn't append
      dropzone.append(imgIn); //this appends
```

Comment: What do you expect `document.createElement('imgIn')` to do?

Comment: that would create an html element <imgIn></imgIn> which isnt wat i need i think. i have much more code thats generating these elements dynamically with numaricaly named id's

Comment: What do you need? Another img element?

Comment: img and imgIn are iterated through as if they are a 2D array of images 15x15 images. i need this to be TWO 2D arryas layerd ontop one another using z-index

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do `reader.addEventListener()` in a loop. You could add the listener once, and then loop inside that.

Comment: the way im trying to allow users to upload an img/gif/mp4 file as a local copy without uploading to the internet made this a sort of necessary step. theirs definitely more elegant solutions but using a img/gif/mp4 into blob into img/gif/mp4 data structure complicated things

Answer (score 1):

You could create just one element and clone it when you append. Then update the original element and append that.

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
const dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropzone');
const imageId = 'imageId_';

img.setAttribute("id", imageId + '1');
img.setAttribute("width", '100px'); // screenWidth / 16 + "px");
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/100'; // reader.result;
dropzone.append(img.cloneNode());

img.setAttribute("id", imageId + '2');
img.setAttribute("width", '100px'); // screenWidth / 16 + "px");
img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000'; // reader.result;
dropzone.append(img);
```

```html
<div id="dropzone"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an `imgIn` element, so that element doesn't render. You should use `img` for both elements.

You should put the loop inside the event listener, instead of adding multiple listeners that all do the same thing.

```
function hueChange() {
  reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
    let imgWidth = window.innerWidth / 16 + "px";

    for (let image = 0; image < mosaicCount; image++) {
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      let imgIn = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute("id", image)
      img.setAttribute("width", imgWidth)
      imgIn.setAttribute("id", "imgIn" + image)
      imgIn.setAttribute("width", imgWidth)
      img.src = reader.result;
      imgIn.src = reader.result;

      dropzone.append(img);
      dropzone.append(imgIn);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you can name elements anything you want with document.createElement('imgIn');

Comment: True, but then you have to define how it renders.

Comment: Yeah and that's exactly what i need to do to achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

Firs problem is you are creating a "custom" element since you are creating an element with "imgIn" so that is not going to render and image.

You can use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and alter the id so you do not have to duplicate id.

```js
const dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropZone');

const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
const image = 1;

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute("id", 'img' + image)
img.setAttribute("width", screenWidth / 16 + "px")
img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/200/300'; // reader.result;
dropzone.append(img);

const imgIn = img.cloneNode(true);
imgIn.setAttribute("id", 'imgIn' + image)
dropzone.append(imgIn);
```

```html
<div id="dropZone"></div>
```